# How to migrate from Kohana 2 (placed into project folder) to Kohana 3 (installed is a module) in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: php, ubuntu, migration, kohana

After updating to Ubuntu 12.10 I found that Kohana 2 don't work. I see only blank pages with 200 OK status (ob_end_flush in system/core/Kohana.php don't calling).

So, is it possible to migrate to Kohana 3 with minimum project changes (all developers of this project will be using Kohana 2 and we use one svn, so I don't want to broke their versions and production that deploys from the same svn)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix: https://gist.github.com/2881489

If you use Kohana lower than 2.4, you must put file Arr.php from 2.4 into your Kohana.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a lot of work while migrating to Kohana 3.

Your application code would be mostly rewrited.

Kohana 3 differs from Kohana 2 with many things - class names, routes, models, directory structure, controller and so on.

So better start new project and implement same logic on new version.

[Here is](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/upgrading) short guide on 2 -> 3 migration from Kohana team.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have new php version with new ubuntu and you are probably using some sort deprecated php code.

Are you setting proper reporting level?

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

My kohana 2 is working fine on newest ubuntu.

If reporting still don't work try to debug your app and find where is bug related to the new php version.